# Script/function working in ISE but not in powershell (easy to reproduce)

Tags: powershell

I have a problem where ISE is not doing the same like the console (console does it wrong) and it is very easy to reproduce in a domain environment on a Server 2016 Domain Controller or a Server 2016 Memberserver with installed ActiveDirectory module.

**c:\temp\main.ps1**

```
Import-Module c:\temp\functions.psm1 -Force
$ObjAdDomain = Get-VarObjAdDomain
$ObjAdDomainPdc = Get-VarStrPDCEmulator
write-host "PDC = $ObjAdDomainPdc"
```

**c:\temp\functions.psm1**

```
function Get-VarObjAdDomain {Get-ADDomain}
function Get-VarStrPDCEmulator {$ObjAdDomain.PDCEmulator}
```

The expected result is, that Powershell made an output like `PDC = server.domain.local` in ISE and in console, but it does only in ISE.
In console the output is only `PDC =` and the variable `$ObjAdDomainPdc` is empty.

This code was working without any problems at Server 2012 R2 but now with Server 2016 it isn't working anymore, but `Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0` has no effect.

I know that I could run the `Get-VarStrPDCEmulator` and give the variable `$ObjAdDomain` to the function, but this is normally not necessary and I would have to change hundreds of function and generate tons of additionally code because of that (bug?).

Does anybody know what is going on here?

Comment: What happens if you remove the Write-Host?

Comment: I don't get your question. If I remove that, there is no output. The write-host is just to see whats in the variable.

Comment: This is a debuging step.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

I don't know why this script behavior is different between Server 2012R2 and Server 2016 or between ISE and console, but since I changed all variables from

"$ObjAdDomain = ..."

to

"$global:ObjAdDomain = ..."

the script is working again.

Comment: Relying on global variables is bad practice in almost any situation you can think of. And that doing so in a module is even worse.

Comment: If this is a bad practice, how could that issue be resolved? This was the only workaround I was able to find to get it working on Server 2016. And... Why is it a bad practice? I thought that is why global variables do exist?

Comment: Pass `$ObjAdDomain` as a parameter to `Get-VarStrPDCEmulator` or have the function call `Get-ADDomain` itself.